# Put Very Long Dependency List at the END of the Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to put a very long list of objects at the END of my Makefile.  I cannot get this code to work. I can see $(LIST) getting assigned in the ASSIGN_LIST macro, however, it seems that $(LIST) is blank for stuff.txt.  I'm a newbie at Make so maybe I'm way off the mark.  (Using Red Hat Linux, GNU Make v3.81.)

```
> cat makefile
define ASSIGN_LIST
LIST = $1
endef

stuff.txt: $(LIST)
    echo $(LIST)

# MUCH MORE CODE HERE

# THIS CODE CONTAINING THE LIST IS AT THE VERY END OF MAKEFILE (i.e. OUT OF THE WAY)
define VERY_LONG_LIST_OF_OBJECTS
aaa \
bbb \
ccc \
ddd \
eee \
fff \
etc
endef

$(info $(call ASSIGN_LIST, $(VERY_LONG_LIST_OF_OBJECTS)))
```

When I run the makefile:

```
> make
make: `stuff.txt' is up to date.
```

I use 'touch' to make the prereqs newer than stuff.txt.  If I swapout "eval" with "info" (last line), I can see this

```
> make
LIST =  aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff etc
make: `stuff.txt' is up to date.
```

Is this even possible?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables that appear in targets or prerequisites are [expanded immediately](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html) when read by make during the parsing of the makefile.  So, this cannot work:

```
stuff.txt: $(LIST)
        echo $(LIST)
...
LIST = ...
```

Here, the prerequisite variable is expanded when make reads that line but the variable inside the recipe is not expanded until later when make wants to build the target.  So the variable is not set yet when parsing the prerequisite, then it gets set, then the recipe is run.

If you want to see what make sees you should use [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) instead:

```
stuff.txt: $(LIST)
        echo $^
```

The best way to do this is delay the prerequisites until after the variable is set.  If you really, really don't want to do that you can use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
stuff.txt: $$(LIST)
        echo $^
```

Comment: OK, the .SECONDEXPANSION works.  I'm new at make and really need to understand the expansion process better.  I've read the GNU Make manual a bunch of times and still haven't got it yet. Can you please suggest a good reference source for make expansion in general? Thx very much.

Comment: The first link I discussed above goes over it pretty clearly I think.  I can't recommend anything else that I think is more clear.  Basically you just have to remember that make proceeds in two steps: first, the entire makefile and all included files, etc. are parsed.  No targets are built here.  The link above describes what is expanded during that phase ("immediate").  Then make goes through and tries to build targets that are out of date.  As part of this recipes are expanded ("deferred").

Comment: The very simple rule is that unless it's in a recipe or on the right-hand of a simple variable assignment, it's expanded immediately when make reads in that line of the makefile.  There may be some special cases, but that's basically it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `eval` on ASSIGN_LIST will only set LIST to the 1st file (because of `LIST = $1`). As a result, stuff.txt only depends on aaa.

As an alternative, add the dependency after setting the variable:

```
define VERY_LONG_LIST_OF_OBJECTS
aaa \
... \
etc
endef

stuff: $(VERY_LONG_LIST_OF_OBJECTS)
```

Comment: There's no `eval` in this makefile; did you mean `call`?  And, call arguments are separated by comma not whitespace, so `$1` will expand to the whole list not just the first word.